# UIProgressview in subclassed UITableViewCell need to be used in other UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, uitableview

I have a subclassed custom `UITableViewCell`, in which I am inserting a progress view in it.

here is how:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {
    applicationDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.height, self.frame.size.height);

        self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake( self.imageView.frame.size.width + 20, self.textLabel.frame.origin.y, self.textLabel.frame.size.width, self.textLabel.frame.size.height);
        progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleDefault];
        progressView.frame = CGRectMake(self.textLabel.frame.origin.x, 50, 150, 100);
        progressView.progress = 0.0f;
        progressView.trackTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        progressView.progressTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
        progressView.tag = 101;
        [progressView setHidden:YES];
        [self.contentView addSubview:progressView];
}
```

Now when in other view controller I want to show this elements only in first cell, so I am trying to hide these elements in other cells. Here is how I am trying to do this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString * cellIdentifier = @"cellId";

    CustomCell * cell = [self.tableview dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == Nil) {

        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

if (indexPath.row == 0) {

            imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(cell.imageView.image, 100);
            filename = cell.textLabel.text;

            [(UIProgressView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:101] setHidden:NO];<==Not Working
}

    return cell;
}
```

How to use this UIElements in custom UITableView subclass in my ViewController ?
I have not used xib file, everything is done programmatically. I have beed playing around this for whole day now, any one with any idea here ?

Answer (score 0):

If only the 1st row needs to show the progress view, why not only use the custom cell for row `0` and then use a standard `UITableViewCell` for rows `>1`?

I would also recommend adding `progressView` to `self.contentView` in an `init` method and not in `layoutSubviews`.  `layoutSubviews` is intended to position the views you already have (not add new ones) because it can be called many times over the lifetime of the cell.

---

I would add a BOOL property to the custom cell that determines if you should show the progress indicator (and removes it when set to NO). In cellForRowAtIndexPath: you could set it appropriately for the given row.

In `CustomCell.h`:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL shouldShowProgressView;
```

In `CustomCell.m`:

```
- (void)setShouldShowProgressView:shouldShowProgressView {
     _shouldShowProgressView = shouldShowProgressView;

     if (shouldShowProgressView) {
           if (self.someProgressView == nil) {
                // add your progress view from scratch
           }

           [self.contentView addSubview:self.someProgressView];

     } else {
           [self.someProgressView removeFromSuperview];
     }
}
```

In your table controller:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellId";
    CustomCell *cell = [self.tableview dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == Nil) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
         cell.shouldShowProgressView = YES;

    } else {
         cell.shouldShowProgressView = NO;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I have relocated the resized my cells imageview and textlabel's and according to their positions I am adjusting the position of the progressView.

Comment: I would add a `BOOL` property to the custom cell that determines if you should show the progress indicator (and removes it when set to `NO`).  In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you could set it appropriately for the given `row`.

Comment: I am sorry @jszunski, I am not sure I am following to what you are saying.. :(